# why is find('input:focus') not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have the following script working in all browsers but not in Safari,
has someone an idea what's the reason for this behaviour?

```js
$(function() {

  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // alert($(this).serialize());
    alert($(this).find('input:focus').attr('name'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="./index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit" name="foo[bar]" value="Senden">
</form>
```

Comment: which element you want to target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to the input using the tab key and press enter, then it does work in Safari.

It appears that clicking on a submit button in that browser will discard the focus before triggering the submit event.

If you want to determine which submit button was clicked, use a click event handler.

```js
$(function() {

  var $last_clicked_submit = null;

  $('form').on('click', ":submit", function(e) {
    $last_clicked_submit = $(this);
  });


  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // alert($(this).serialize());
    alert($last_clicked_submit.attr('name'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="./index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit" name="foo[bar]" value="Senden">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution :)